# The role of "free functions" in C generic data structure implementations

Tags: c

I'm writing generic data structure implementations on C for learning purposes (using `void` pointers), however I'm a bit confused about the role of the "free function" that virtually all generic implementations allow the user to pass to the initializer function.

Let's say I have a stack. Should I call the user provided free function when the client calls the "pop" operation, for instance? From one side, if we free the element after accessing it, and before returning it to the caller, by the time the caller receives the value accessing that memory will be undefined behaviour, however if we don't delete it, the user will be responsible for doing so, defeating the purpose of passing a custom free function in the first place.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Just be safe with `free`. Only free elements when your **completely** done with them. Most of the time you will free at the end.

Comment: Please link to any references you are reading referring to custom free functions, as this question may be context-specific.

Comment: Do your generic structure implementations also get an 'allocate' function? If not, what is the 'free' function for?  If so, what is the 'allocate' function used to allocate — because you should use the 'free' function to free what the 'allocate' function allocated.  In the context of a stack, you need to think about which code owns which data.  Is the value passed to the 'push' function copied to the stack?  How is the value passed?  How does the generic code know how big the value is?  There's a lot of information not specified which means it is hard to give a generic answer.

Comment: Going to comment my answer. Stackoverflow C programmers are sometimes stupid and keep talking about irrelevant stuff and downvote decent answers for their own.  Your stack should not be responsible for freeing user allocated memory. Your stack should only free its `Nodes`. `void push(void *item)` would allocate a `Node` and set its value to `item`. When the user calls `void* pop()`, you retrieve that node's value, free the node, and return the `value` that it had. Since the user allocated `item` it should be their responsibility to deallocate it. Original answer: http://pastebin.com/cEhE9SN8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say I have a stack. Should I call the user provided free
>   function when the client calls the "pop" operation, for instance?

No, you should not free the element when it is pop'ed from the stack. The user expects to get the object back that he earlier push'ed on the stack. And then it must be valid, of course.
During a pop operation you only should free your own data that you needed to store the user's object.

> I'm a bit confused about the role of the "free function" that
>   virtually all generic implementations allow the user to pass to the
>   initializer function.

The custom free functions I am aware of, are only used when the whole management data structure is destroyed. Then in addition to your management data like list nodes etc., the user data also has to be freed.

As you do not know if there are dynamically allocated objects enclosed in that user data which require some additional handling, you can only leave this at user's hand.
For this purpose the user has to pass a free function.

Answer (score 0):

you always need to know how to destroy externally created objects to avoid memory leaks.

For your stack example, what happens if a user pushes an object and then destroys the stack? The stack destructor should call the destructors of all the elements it still contains.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, you should always have a function dedicated for freeing everything you malloc-ed during your program. You can do it at the end, or just when you're sure you won't **ever** need it after that.